# Compiling Python src into a binary executable using PySide

Tags: python, pyside

I'm trying to compile the Python src files of the following Github repo using PySide: https://github.com/Bohdan-Khomtchouk/PubData

To accomplish this, I've tried the following tools:

1) http://www.pyinstaller.org

2) http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net

3) http://www.py2exe.org

since I'm trying to compile this Python src into a binary executable on both a Windows and Mac OS X system (using PySide).  However, I couldn't find a single authoritative source that gives step-by-step instructions on how to do this in PySide, i.e., a compile-some-arbitrary-Python-repo-on-Github-using-PySide-101 crash course in Python.  Can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: there should be one on pyQt, I think

Comment: @YOU I did `brew install pyside` and then got majorly lost on what to do next...